# Does there exist a website wrapper app for iOS and Android?

Tags: php, android, ios, mobile

Without diving deep into programming for iOS and Android, is it possible to wrap a responsive PHP-based webpage in a *wrapper* that we *lock* to our url, and present it as our own app?

Also is it possible to make this *app* remember the users login session and other options (cookies)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, both Android and iOS support "webviews" (each platform has their own name for it).

In your app, you would simply launch into a webview with the URL that you hard code within the app yourself. Both platform webviews should also support storing cookies too.

Although, since you're wanting something this lightweight, you may want to consider a cross-platform development framework such as React-Native, Cordova/PhoneGap, etc. So that you only have to write the code once and deploy to both iOS and Android.